# PDF Print to different email client?

Tags: mail.app, email, pdf

I’ve been experimenting with [MimeStream](https://mimestream.com) as my email client and I generally like it. I did the thing of going into Mail’s preferences¹ to change the default email program so most of the time everything works as expected.

Except that one of my occasional workflows is to email a PDF of a document by selecting “Send in Mail” from the PDF menu at the bottom of the print dialog. This opens Mail.app and not Mimestream to send the email. Is there anywhere I can change this so that it will use my preferred email client?

---

1. It seems bizarre that this setting lives there and not in the System Settings app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put an alias of your mail app in `~/Library/PDF Services`. (If the folder does not exist, you can create it.)

Your alias will then appear in the PDF drop-down menu of the print dialog, and the OS will pass the PDF to your app.

(In fact, the "Send in Mail" item is also just an alias to Mail.app.)

You can rename the alias to "**Send in MimeStream**" or whatever you like.